# What is the best way to call a web service in background?

Tags: android, background, alarmmanager, scheduling

I have an Android app I need to call a web service in the background every one minute and depending on web service response send a notification to the user if there is a ticket is opened for him. What is the best way to do this? please note that target SDK is 26

Comment: by `in background` do you mean, while app is active on background thread or literally when app is in background?

Comment: when the app is not active I mean the user doesn't use the application regardless of the app in background or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
The new JobService must be registered in the Android manifest with the BIND_JOB_SERVICE 
permission.

 <service
        android:name=".TestJobService"
        android:label="Word service"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" >

 </service>
```

Create the following utility class.

```
 public class Util {

// schedule the start of the service every 10 - 30 seconds
public static void scheduleJob(Context context) {
     ComponentName serviceComponent = new ComponentName(context, 
 TestJobService.class);
    JobInfo.Builder builder = new JobInfo.Builder(0, serviceComponent);
    builder.setMinimumLatency(1 * 1000); // wait at least
    builder.setOverrideDeadline(3 * 1000); // maximum delay
    //builder.setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_UNMETERED); // require unmetered network
    //builder.setRequiresDeviceIdle(true); // device should be idle
    //builder.setRequiresCharging(false); // we don't care if the device is charging or not
    JobScheduler jobScheduler = context.getSystemService(JobScheduler.class);
    jobScheduler.schedule(builder.build());
}

}
```

Create the following receiver

```
public class MyStartServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Util.scheduleJob(context);
}
}
```

Register the receiver in the Android manifest for the BOOT_COMPLETED event.

```
<receiver android:name="MyStartServiceReceiver" >
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
</intent-filter>
```

Create your job

```
  /**
  * JobService to be scheduled by the JobScheduler.
  * start another service
  */
public class TestJobService extends JobService {
private static final String TAG = "SyncService";

@Override
public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {
    Intent service = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LocalWordService.class);
    getApplicationContext().startService(service);
    Util.scheduleJob(getApplicationContext()); // reschedule the job
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
    return true;
}

}
```

refer this link

https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTaskScheduling/article.html